# Does iCloud Drive sync while in sleep or while locked on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, icloud, sleep-wake

I've been digging through Google and Apple's iCloud documentation, and I haven't been able to find a clear answer on this.

Photos do sync while locked, but I'm more interested how to keep iCloud uploads going while *I* sleep.

Comment: No concrete source on this, but would be a reasonable guess to assume that all activity continues when locked and all activity stops during sleep based on the nature of the applications. If you really want to check, you can run something like Little Snitch and see for yourself.

Comment: That makes sense. I wish Cloud Drive was less of a black box. There's so much about how it operates that is a mystery.